# Qt Signal Slot No Matching Function For Call To

Tags: qt

I get the following error:

mainwindow.cpp:168: error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(MainWindow*, const char*, MediaPlayer*&, const char*)'
     QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(PlayMedia()), _MediaPlayer, SLOT(PlayMedia()));
                                                                                ^

C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtCore\qobject.h:213: error: no type named 'Object' in 'struct QtPrivate::FunctionPointer'

**MediaPlayer Class:**

```
class MediaPlayer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MediaPlayer();
    ~MediaPlayer();


public slots:
    void OnPlayMedia();
...


void MediaPlayer::OnPlayMedia()
{
    qDebug() << "PlayMedia";
}
```

**MainWindow Class:**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void PlayMedia();

private:
    MediaPlayer *mMediaPlayer;
...


void MainWindow::Initialize()
{
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    connect(this, SIGNAL(PlayMedia), mMediaPlayer, SLOT(OnPlayMedia));
    ...
}
```

But I get the error everytime I build the project

**Update 1:**
I update the code but I still get the error

**update 2**
The problem was that MediaPlayer was missing QObject

```
class MediaPlayer : public QObject
```

Adding this fixed the code.

Comment: Never create any symbol with leading `_`

Comment: And the slot name is `OnPlayMedia`.

Comment: I changed it to mMediaPlayer and I get the same error

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still get the error
btw C# _aField is used for private fields which I'm originating from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaPlayer should be derived from QObject:

```
class MediaPlayer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MediaPlayer(QObject* parent=0):QObject(parent){/* your init here*/}
    ~MediaPlayer();


public slots:
    void OnPlayMedia();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, especially for the params on the constructor.  I got it to work but updated my code to pass QObject

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my class MediaPlayer was missing inheritance of QObject.  I updated my original code above to show this